# How to Append the values of ValueQuryset to array?

Tags: django

My View.py:

```
from django.db.models import Count
def test1(request):
    states = Loksabha.objects.values('state').distinct('state')
    terms = Loksabha.objects.values('term').distinct('term')
    dataset = Loksabha.objects.all()
    state_filter=Loksabha.objects.filter(state='Maharashtra',term='Fourteenth Lok Sabha(2004-  09)').annotate(num=Count('party',distinct=True))
    age_filter=state_filter.values('party').annotate(Count('party'))
    xdata=[]
    ydata=[]
    for b in state_filter:
        xdata.append(b.party)
        ydata.append(b.num)
    chartdata = {'x': xdata, 'y': ydata}
    charttype = "pieChart"
    chartcontainer = 'piechart_container'
```

i have used django-nvd3 to display the graph my state_filter query answer  is coreect but i cant  understand the pass the value of ValueQueryset to `xdata[]` and `ydata[]`. my state_filter queryset value pass to the `age_filter`

`age_filter` value is:

```
[{'party': 'Shiv Sena', 'party__count': 14},
 {'party': 'Indian Nationlist Congress', 'party__count': 15},
 {'party': 'Nationlist Congress Party', 'party__count': 9},
 {'party': 'Republican Party of India(A)', 'party__count': 1},
 {'party': 'Bharatiya Janata Party', 'party__count': 14},
 {'party': 'Independent', 'party__count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ValueQuerySet yields dictionaries. Get items by indexing, instead of accessing attributes.

Replace following lines:

```
for b in state_filter:
    xdata.append(b.party)
    ydata.append(b.num)
```

with:

```
for d in age_filter:
    xdata.append(b['party'])
    ydata.append(b['party_count'])
```