# Using Django and Charts.js, no data sent to template from view

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts, chart.js

I'm using charts.js with Django and I have an issue with the data I'm sending from the view to the chart in the template.
Here is my code:

**model.py** (only relevant fields):

```
STATUS = ((0,"Tender"),
    (1,"Live"),
    (2,"Archived"))


class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)    
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    project_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=0)
    project_designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=0, related_name='project_designer')
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=0, related_name='project_manager')
    is_fire = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project_status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    #progress
    progress_abdrawings = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(100),MinValueValidator(0)])
    @property
    def abdrawings_remaining(self):
        remaining = 100 - self.progress_abdrawings
        return remaining


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-project_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_number
```

**views.py** (only relevant fields):
I only want to display two fields on this chart: *progress_abdrawings* and *abdrawings_remaining*

```
def ProjectDetail(request, slug):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'detail-project.html'
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'detail-project.html',{'project':project})

class ChartView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

class ChartAbProgress(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    model = Project

    def get(self, slug):
        self.slug = slug
        labels = ['COMPLETED',
            'REMAINING']
        chartLabel = "FAB DRAWINGS"
        chartdata = []
        queryset = Project.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).order_by('-project_number')
        for project in queryset:            
            chartdata.append(project.progress_abdrawings)
            chartdata.append(project.abdrawings_remaining)   
        abProgData = {
                     "labels":labels,
                     "chartLabel":chartLabel,
                     "chartdata":chartdata,
             }
        return Response(abProgData)
```

**url.py** (only relevant fields):

```
urlpatterns = [

    # The home page
    path('', views.DashView.as_view(), name='home'),

    # project detail
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.ProjectDetail, name='project_detail'),

    # project charts
    path('dashboard/', views.ChartView.as_view()),
    path('ab-pro', views.ChartAbProgress.as_view()) 
    ]
```

**detail-project.html** (only relevant fields):

```
<div class="card-body">
     <div class="chart-container">
           <canvas id="abProChart"></canvas>
      </div>
</div>

{% block javascripts %}

    var endpointAbPro = '/ab-pro';
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpointAbPro,
        success: function (data) {
            drawAbProChart(data, 'abProChart');
            console.log("ab progress");
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log(error_data);
        }
    })
    // AB progress chart
    function drawAbProChart(fabProgData, id) {
        var labels = fabProgData.labels;
        var chartLabel = fabProgData.chartLabel;
        var chartdata = fabProgData.chartdata;
        console.log(chartdata)
        var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: chartLabel,
                    data: chartdata,
                    backgroundColor: [

                        "#bdbdbd",
                        "#27cc84",
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'white',
                        'white',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
                           },

            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                },
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        left: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 20
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
</script>

{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Please notice in the script I'm printing the data, this is the result in console, no data:
[image: console]

And this is what I get in browser, no chart:
[image: charts.js]

Comment: Hi, what does `console.log(chartdata)` printing  show full json structure ?

Comment: Hi @Swati, how do I see that?

Comment: Inside your browser console you will see output of `console.log(chartdata)` .Also you said in question *.. no data* so your server doesn't return any data ?

Comment: I did attached a picture showing the output of  ```console.log(chartdata)```

Comment: It prints what's shown on the screenshot, but there is no data, only an empty json structure

Comment: Then , check at your server code if `"chartdata":chartdata` has any value or not .

Comment: I get this: {'labels': ['COMPLETED', 'REMAINING'], 'chartLabel': 'FAB DRAWINGS', 'chartdata': []}

Comment: that's *abProgData*

Comment: it looks like it's not appending the data in views.py

Comment: Hi, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21669404/10606400) works. Also , make sure your queryset has data in it (row are been fetched)